# VC++: How to get the time and date of a file?

Tags: c++, windows, file, date, size

How do I get the file size and date stamp of a file on Windows in C++, given its path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `FindFirstFile()` to get them both at once, without having to open it (which is required by `GetFileSize()` and `GetInformationByHandle()`). It's a bit laborious, however, so a little wrapper is helpful

```
bool get_file_information(LPCTSTR path, WIN32_FIND_DATA* data)
{
  HANDLE h = FindFirstFile(path, &data);
  if(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != h) {
    return false;
  } else {
    FindClose(h);
    return true;
  }
}
```

Then the file size is available in the `nFileSizeHigh` and `nFileSizeLow` members of [WIN32_FIND_DATA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365740(VS.85).aspx), and the timestamps are available in the `ftCreationTime`, `ftLastAccessTime` and `ftLastWriteTime` members.

Comment: There are three errors in your example, and it should be noted how to decode the time stamp: call FileTimeToSystemTime. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Oops. Writing in haste! Fixed now. :-)

Answer (score 3):

[GetFileSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364955(VS.85).aspx)/[GetFileSizeEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364957(VS.85).aspx) and [GetFileInformationByHandleEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364953(VS.85).aspx) with FileBasicInfo can be used to retrieved this information.

Both functions take a handle, so you need to use CreateFile on the path prior to calling these functions.

```
// Error handling removed for brevity
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(path, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ,
                 NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

LARGE_INTEGER fileSize;
GetFileSizeEx(hFile, &fileSize);

FILE_BASIC_INFO fileInfo);
GetFileInformationByHandle(hFile, FileBasicInfo, fileInfo, sizeof(fileInfo));

// fileInfo.CreationTime is when file was created.
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also use [POSIX stat](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/stat.html), if you were looking for portability. Windows still supports its use.

Answer (score 3):

To append the other answer, you call [GetFileTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724320(VS.85).aspx) to get just the file times.  This API also requries a handle and I think is easier than GetFileInformationByHandle API.  BTW the GetFileInformationByHandleEx is only supported in VISTA and above.

Comment: I swore this api existed, but my search for GetFileTimes (note the s) came up with nothing.  Good catch.

Comment: My answer was more meant to be a add-on to yours anyway.  I see yours as a more complete answer to the question, which is why I voted yours up.