# How to use GetFileTime in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to get the last write time of a file in VC++ but I think I am writing the file handle in a wrong way can you help me find the right way to write the file handle for example my directory is "D:/start.txt"

here is my code

```
LPFILETIME ftWrite; 

HANDLE hFileMap;
hFileMap  = CreateFileMapping(L"D:/start.txt".txt", NULL, PAGE_READONLY, 0, 1, NULL);

GetFileTime(hFileMap, NULL, NULL, ftWrite);
```

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051667/vc-how-to-get-the-time-and-date-of-a-file

Comment: _"my directory is "D:/start.txt""_ Really?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I using VC++ and it show me error when i don't use the L and it suggest to add the L and then it compiles error free I don't know why the L to be honest

Comment: @MohamedBeltagy: Then look it up. `L""` is a wide string literal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried this code, and it worked.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>    

int main(void)
{

    HANDLE hFile1;
    FILETIME ftCreate;
    SYSTEMTIME stUTC, stLocal;
    hFile1 = CreateFile("mytestfile.txt", GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ,  NULL,  OPEN_EXISTING,  FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

    if(hFile1 == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("Could not open file, error %ul\n", GetLastError());
        return -1;
    }

    if(!GetFileTime(hFile1, &ftCreate, NULL, NULL))
    {
        printf("Something wrong!\n");
        return FALSE;
    }

    FileTimeToSystemTime(&ftCreate, &stUTC);
    printf("UTC System Time format:\n");
    printf("Created on: %02d/%02d/%d %02d:%02d\n", stUTC.wDay, stUTC.wMonth, stUTC.wYear, stUTC.wHour, stUTC.wMinute);

    return 0;

}
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks :) that worked for me but I had to change two things, I am using VC++ MFC  

::FILETIME ftCreate;      

the eplaination is here
Sound like you've got at least two definitions of FILETIME.  One comes from <windows.h> and is in the global namespace.  The other could come from System::Runtime::InteropServices.  Spell out the full name.  If you want the global one, you should use ::FILETIME.

Comment: and here 
 hFile1 = CreateFile(L"start.txt", GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);   
I had to add an L before the directory

Comment: @MohamedBeltagy: You seem to be confusing directories and files.